# Why is my docker container's timestamp wrong when running an ASP.NET Framework 4.7 application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, docker

I have a very simple ASP.NET v4.7 web application that runs in a docker container on my local development laptop.

The web application tries to connect to DocumentDb, but this fails because the container's timestamp is completely wrong, so naturally Jwt token verification fails. The exact ASP.NET code does not really matter; this is more about why the docker container's timestamp is different from the host machine.

Note that I'm using windows containers. My dockerFile looks as follows:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

When I connect to the container, and run "time", I get the following:

```
docker container exec -it <containerId> cmd
c:\>time
The current time is:  0:29:49.87

c:\>tzutil /g
South Africa Standard Time
```

When I do this on the host machine, my laptop, I get:

```
C:\>time
The current time is: 15:42:45.72
Enter the new time:

C:\>tzutil /g
South Africa Standard Time
```

Where does docker get that crazy timestamp? Is there a way to sync with the host machine on startup?

My laptop's operating system version is: Win 10, v1803 (build 17134.471)
I'm running: Docker for Windows CE v2.0.0.0-win81 (29211) with Docker Engine version 18.09.0

Comment: Possible related github issue? https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-docker/issues/120

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only solution so far is to "Wait and let it marinate" as pointed out in http://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-docker/issues/120

Thanks @ikkentim for pointing out the issue.

I suspected that perhaps my container did not have internet access and could not sync its clock, but was unable to verify this as it just started working fine this morning.

I will post a better answer if I find a more useful solution than "wait".